# How to count time in socket

Tags: c, sockets, timer, client-server, time.h

I have a simple server-client program which acts according to the received data from client.

When the received data is string `start` I want the server to count time in seconds until it receives `stop` command from client, and as server receives `stop` server sends back counted seconds to the client.

I'm new in C programming and I don't know how to use `time.h` library. I have tried to use some commands, but got few errors.

```
/* tcpserver.c */
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/sysinfo.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "address.h"
int main() {
    int sock, connected, bytes_recieved , true = 1, number;  
    char send_data [1024] , recv_data[1024];       
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr,client_addr; 
    struct sysinfo info;   
    int sin_size;
    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
        perror("Socket");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (setsockopt(sock,SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR,&true,sizeof(int)) == -1) {
        perror("Setsockopt");
        exit(1);
    }
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;         
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(1237);     
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; 
    bzero(&(server_addr.sin_zero),8); 
    if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr))
                                                               == -1) {
        perror("Unable to bind");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (listen(sock, 5) == -1) {
        perror("Listen");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf ("\nTCPServer Waiting for client on port 1237");
    fflush(stdout);
    number = 0;
    while(1) {  
        sin_size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
        connected = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr,&sin_size);
    printf("\n I got a connection from (%s , %d)",
    inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr),ntohs(client_addr.sin_port));
    send(connected, "Hello, this is simple program.", 100, 1);
    while (1) {
        printf("\n SEND (q or Q to quit) : ");
        fgets(send_data, sizeof(send_data), stdin);
        bytes_recieved = recv(connected,recv_data,1024,0);
        recv_data[bytes_recieved] = '\0';
        if (strcmp(favoriteDairyProduct, "start") == 0 || strcmp(favoriteDairyProduct, "START") == 0) {
        // count the time until stop is recieved


        }
        printf("\n RECIEVED DATA = %s " , recv_data);
        fflush(stdout);   
        send(connected, send_data,strlen(send_data), 0);  
      }       
    }
    close(sock);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the client code. One other thing I would like to do is to change the program to receive multiple clients. But for now timer is more important.

```
/* tcpclient.c */
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/sysinfo.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include "address.h"
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    int sock, bytes_recieved, number;  
    char send_data[1024],recv_data[1024];
    struct hostent *host;
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;  
    struct sysinfo info;   
    host = gethostbyname("127.0.0.1");
    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
        perror("Socket");
        exit(1);
    }
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;     
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(1237);   
    server_addr.sin_addr = *((struct in_addr *)host->h_addr);
    bzero(&(server_addr.sin_zero),8); 
    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1) {
        perror("Connect");
        exit(1);
    }
    while(1) {
        bytes_recieved = recv(sock,recv_data,1024,0);
        recv_data[bytes_recieved] = '\0';
        printf("\nRecieved data = %s " , recv_data);
        printf("\nSEND (q or Q to quit) : ");
        fgets(send_data, sizeof(send_data), stdin);        
        send(sock,send_data, sizeof(send_data), 0);
    }   
    close(sock);         
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the platform you are on, you could use gettimeofday() when you receive both the start and stop messages.

```
#include <sys/time.h>

struct timeval t1, t2;
if (<received start command>) {
    gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);
}
if (<received stop command>) {
    gettimeofday(&t2, NULL);
}
```

Each gives you the current time in seconds and microseconds. You have to find the difference between the two.

```
time_t diff_sec = t2.tv_sec - t1.tv_sec;
suseconds_t diff_usec = t2.tv_usec - t1.tv_usec;
```

Of course you have to take into account that t2.tv_usec could be smaller than t1.tv_usec.

You should also verify that you have received a start before a stop, or the results won't make sense.

I'll leave the rest as an exercise to the reader since this looks like homework.